# std::bind and non-virtual call to base class method

Tags: c++

I want to use `std::bind` and do non-virtual call to base class function eg: `derived_obj.BaseClass::foo()`

Example:

Let's say I have base class **A** and derived class **B**. **A** has a virtual function `foo()` which is overridden by **B**.

```
class A
{
   public:
     virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Hello from A::foo()!";}
}

class B : public A
{
   public:
     void foo() overide { std::cout << "Hello from B::foo()!";}
}
```

If I want to call `A::foo()` from object of class **B** I do non-virtual call:

```
B b_obj;
b_obj.A::foo(); // prints "Hello from A::foo()!"
```

Now I want to use `std::bind` and do non-virtual call to `A::foo()` from b_obj, how do I do this?

I've already tried by casting `b_obj` to **A** and use address of `&A::foo()`, but had no luck.

```
auto f = std::bind(&A::foo, static_cast<A*>(&b_obj));
f(); // prints "Hello from B::foo()!" but it should print "Hello from A::foo()!"
```

Comment: You could wrap a call to lambda. Not seeing how to do it with bind though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here. You should either do the non-virtual call in a *lambda* or you go the trusty old way of *slicing the object* (which is a copy) you want to pass to `std::bind`.

```
// Base method
B b_obj; b_obj.A::foo(); // prints "Hello from A::foo()!"

// First method
auto k = [](auto b){ b.A::foo(); };
k(b_obj);

// Second method
auto f = std::bind(&A::foo, *static_cast<A*>(&b_obj));
f();
```

This all prints:

```
Hello from A::foo()!
Hello from A::foo()!
Hello from A::foo()!
```

The *Second method* works (slices) since `std::bind` copies its arguments. You should *really prefer* a lambda.

Comment: You call bind with a different object here - you created a new copy of type A based on b_obj.

Comment: @Dutow, is there a better way to slice?

Comment: @Dutow thanks for pointing this out. I've solved this now by combining lambda and `std::bind` eg.: `std::bind([](auto* b){ b->A::foo(); }, &b_obj);`

Comment: @WhiZTiM I don't have a better idea if you want to slice it, but it can be solved without it.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the call inside a lambda:

```
B b_obj;
auto f = std::bind([&b_obj]() { b_obj.A::foo(); } );
```

But this makes little sense unless you can only use `std::bind` somewhere (for example because of `std::is_bind_expression`), as you pass the object parameter to the lambda's capture, not to bind.

Otherwise just using a lambda or `std::function` without `bind` should be cleaner.